# How to use boto3 to add Security Group rule between Security Groups of different accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I am fairly new to the world of boto3 and am attempting to use it (version 1.7.57) to
a) Create a Security Group in Account A, VPC A (let's call it sg-a)
b) Create a Security Group in Account B, VPC B (let's call it sg-b)
c) Create a set of rules that lets them talk to each other

a) and b) are easy enough using

```
ec2_client.create_security_group(...)
```

**Update:** 
Adding some more information on the create_security_group call for completeness. If you use the ec2 client create_security_group() call (as opposed to the VPC Resource flavor), and you don't want the security group to be created in the default VPC, be sure to include the VpcId parameter.

```
ec2_client.create_security_group
(  
    Description='This is a description',
    GroupName='SecurityGroupTest',
    VpcId=some_vpc_id
)
```

**End Update**

I get the security group IDs (say "sg-a" and "sg-b") from the return for those calls and then try to use those to make the rule:

```
ec2_client.authorize_security_group_ingress(
    FromPort=80,
    ToPort=80,
    IpProtocol='tcp',
    GroupId='sg-a',
    SourceGroup='sg-b',
    GroupOwner='Account B's ID'
)
```

This results in the following error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "GroupOwner", must be one of: CidrIp, FromPort, GroupId, GroupName, IpPermissions, IpProtocol, SourceSecurityGroupName, SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId, ToPort, DryRun
Unknown parameter in input: "SourceGroup", must be one of: CidrIp, FromPort, GroupId, GroupName, IpPermissions, IpProtocol, SourceSecurityGroupName, SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId, ToPort, DryRun
```

This seems to deviate from the AWS API documentation
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/authorize-security-group-ingress.html
which lists `source-group` and `group-owner` as valid parameters for the AWS API `authorize-security-group-ingress` call. In fact,

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-a  --protocol tcp --port 80 --source-group sg-b --group-owner <Accont B's ID>
```

works beautifully.

So.... I'm guessing that either
a) boto3 just hasn't been updated to support those parameters yet
or
b) I'm missing something.

I'm hoping I'm missing something.

Comment: Be careful not to confuse boto3 API documentation and details with AWS CLI commands and documentation.

Comment: I understand they are not the same thing, but as I understand it, boto3 would **strive** towards parity with the underlying AWS API. This looks like a case where it just hasn't caught up yet, but I wanted to make sure I didn't miss something.  :)

Comment: Note that the underlying AWS API is not the same as the AWS CLI. There typically is not equivalence between boto3 and the CLI, though there is from a feature perspective. Here's the underlying API for [`AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress.html).

Comment: I am trying to code this up using Python. I cannot get past the error "The security group 'sg-example' does not exist (it does). I have setup VPC peering between two accounts. I still cannot get it two work. I also cannot get your AWS CLI example to work either. Can you provide more details on the AWS CLI command, your environment, a screenshot of the security group rule that your command created.

Comment: The error message appears to be giving you at least part of the answer: the parameter is called `SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId`, not `GroupOwner`.

Comment: Are both VPCs in the same AWS account?

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm assuming that since you updated your answer, you got past the "The Security group 'sg-example' does not exist" error. :)  
But, as I was getting that same error this morning when trying to test your solution and in case anyone comes here later, I'll update my question with some more detail on the create_security_group call.

Comment: The problem with security group does not exist was cause by trying to add a security group in a different region. You can create VPC peering across regions but your cannot specify security groups in different regions. They must be in the same region. I eventually found documentation that actually said this. Then my code worked correctly.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - I eventually figured this out. I just added a comment about security groups need to be in the same region.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - Different accounts. My problem was different regions which is not supported. My answer now shows how to use security groups across accounts / VPCs in the same region.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is working code.

Notes:

1. You must have VPC Peering enabled.
2. Security Groups only work within the same region. You cannot specify a security group in a different region.

Python:

```
ip_perm = [{
    'IpProtocol': 'tcp',
    'FromPort': 22,
    'ToPort': 22,
    'UserIdGroupPairs': [{
        'GroupId': src_sg_id,   # ID (starts with sg-...)
        'UserId': src_account   # The account number of the other side
    }]
}]

response = client.authorize_security_group_ingress(
    IpPermissions=ip_perm,
    GroupId=sg_id)      # This is the security group to add the rule to
```

Note: If you want to do this in the console specify the "inbound source" as accountno/sg-id.

Comment: And it does not deviate at all from the AWS boto3 documentation on [`authorize_security_group_ingress`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.authorize_security_group_ingress)

Comment: I found the IpPermissions part of the docs on the train ride home from work on Friday and also saw your response here. Had to wait until this morning (Monday) to test it out, but it is indeed working!

Greatly appreciate your assistance!